# Jenkins integration with Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to intregate jenkins in visual studio team services as a service hook. The idea is when a code to master branch is pushed, launch a job of jenkins automatically. Everything seems to be configured correctly but when the event occurs, it gives an error:

```
"An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to connect to the remote server"
```

The request is the notifyCommit url that if I paste in the browser works and it launches the jenkins job. So, it seems that something is not correctly configured because from team services cannot connect to Jenkins.

```
"Error Details
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> 
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the  
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"
```

Comment: Where are your Jenkins server hosted? Locally/On-premise?

Comment: is not in the cloud, is installed in a public virtual machine in our organization that is accesible in any computer of our domain.

Comment: Is the VM in the DMZ/Accessable from the outside world? Because if you are using VSTSO (Visual Studio Team Services Online) then it has no access to your internal domain or network.

Comment: No, so I cannot trigger a jenkins job automatically from team services? Other idea was to do a post-receive hook manually in Git but as I am using Pull Request in team services I cannot do that.

Comment: Yep, since your build server is within your network, VSTSO cant access it. Hence the "Unable to connect to the remote server" error. If you have the required licenses, you could spin up your own Team Services server / Team Foundation Server within your organization. If you need further assistance in setting up your TFS server, lets take it on mail pnw(a)lego.com

Comment: Ok, thanks but we don't want to have the server within our organization. Anyway, thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: Ah ok, however - Then you have to either open op the network for connections to the Jenkins build server or host the buildserver in maybe Azure or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your Jenkins build server is hosted within your organizations network.

To solve it, you could host your build server in fx Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins was not accessible because is not public outside.